# Unit/Kernel tests are not completing

Tags: testing

I am currently unable to run my Kernel tests on my server. I am running the test  from within the Drupal UI but they error out with:

```
"PHPunit Test failed to complete; Error:"
```

with a log messages of

```
Notice: Undefined index: error in Drupal\simpletest\Form\SimpletestResultsForm::addResultForm()
```

and

```
The file public://simpletest/verbose was not deleted because it does not exist.
```

Comment: I am not sure if things have changed; but the last time I was using the test runner UI I was told it isn't all that maintained and to use the command line to execute the tests. If you use the command line, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this error when phpunit was missing executable permission.

It also failed from the command line, but the error message was clear

> sh: 1: XXX/web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit: Permission denied